# Starting from activity B, how can I go back to activity A without killing B so that I can go back to B without creating it agan?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Is it possible to go back from `Activity B` to `Activity A` without killing `Activity B` so that you can go back to `B` again without creating a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Call `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that points to A. By default, this will create a fresh instance of A; if that's not what you want, add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to the `Intent`.

From the *user's* standpoint, though, you're likely to confuse them, as this will scramble the back stack. I would recommend that you find some other solution for whatever problem you are perceiving (e.g., use a better process-level cache, if your problem is loading data).